# invalid characters happens by using truncate(0) in python

Tags: python, truncate, invalid-characters

I used truncate(0) in python to overwrite data on my file. Part of the code is like this:

```
l=f.readlines()
f.truncate(0)
    for w in l:
        data=w.split()
        if 105==int(data[0]): 
            f.write('%s %s\n'%((str(data[0]),str(np.mean(b)))))
        else:
            f.write('%s %s\n'%((str(data[0]),(data[1]))))
```

The code works fine and output is correct, but when I open the output file (which is in txt format) I got "invalid characters" errors. At the head of the output file, I have this extra data:

```
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
```

And the bad character error is for these extra data. After this invalid-characters, I have the data of output, made by python, which is correct.

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because after the `f.readlines()` call, the file position is still set to the original end of file.  `truncate` doesn't change the file position, so when you write your string, it pads out to the old end of file with zeros.  Just do `f.seek(0)` before you truncate.